# Create user using freshdesk PHP api

Tags: php, freshdesk

I'm implementing freshdesk API's for one of my project.

Using freshdesk PHP API I tried to create new user but i'm getting internal server error when I run the code in postman plugin and i'm using SLIM framework for my project.

Please check my below code and thanks in advance!

**PHP:**

```
<?php    
 $api_key = "MY_API_KEY";
 $password = "xyz123M";
 $mydomain = "MY_DOMAIN";

 $custom_fields = array(
 "department" => "Accounts"
 );
 $contact_data = json_encode(array(
    "user_name" => "Sri Jitthu",
    "email_id" => "srij@mydomain.com"
 ));

 $url = "https://$mydomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/contacts";

 $ch = curl_init($url);
 $header[] = "Content-type: application/json";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_key:$password");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contact_data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
 $headers = substr($server_output, 0, $header_size);
 $response = substr($server_output, $header_size);

 if($info['http_code'] == 201) {
 echo "Contact created successfully, the response is given below \n";
 echo "Response Headers are \n";
 echo $headers."\n";
 echo "Response Body \n";
 echo "$response \n";
 } 
 else 
  {
   if($info['http_code'] == 404) 
     {
      echo "Error, Please check the end point \n";
     } 
     else 
     {
      echo "Error, HTTP Status Code : " . $info['http_code'] . "\n";
      echo "Headers are ".$headers."\n";
      echo "Response is ".$response;
     }
     }

     curl_close($ch);
  ?>
```

Comment: Any other errors you're getting?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, I'm getting validation errors in user_name and email_id prarameters from freshdesk

Answer (score 0):

I have used same freshdesk PHP API. I think the parameters that you have defined is not acceptable by fresh desk.We need to pass the parameters as they defined.

Instead of passing `user_name` you should pass `name` also instead of passing `email_id` you should pass `email`.

As well as when you're passing custom fields in your API means that should exists or predefined in your account then only it will work. for ex you're passing `department` is `Accounts` in your API which means the `Accounts` should be predefined in your freshdesk account.

Check the below code and try. Hope it will help you.

**PHP:**

```
<?php    
 $api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY";
 $password = "xyz";
 $yourdomain = "YOUR_DOMAIN";

 $custom_fields = array(
 "department" => "Accounts"
 );
 $contact_data = json_encode(array(
    "name" => "Sri Jitthu",
    "email" => "srij@mydomain.com"
 ));

 $url = "https://$yourdomain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/contacts";

 $ch = curl_init($url);
 $header[] = "Content-type: application/json";
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$api_key:$password");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $contact_data);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
 $headers = substr($server_output, 0, $header_size);
 $response = substr($server_output, $header_size);

 if($info['http_code'] == 201) {
 echo "Contact created successfully, the response is given below \n";
 echo "Response Headers are \n";
 echo $headers."\n";
 echo "Response Body \n";
 echo "$response \n";
 } 
 else 
  {
   if($info['http_code'] == 404) 
     {
      echo "Error, Please check the end point \n";
     } 
     else 
     {
      echo "Error, HTTP Status Code : " . $info['http_code'] . "\n";
      echo "Headers are ".$headers."\n";
      echo "Response is ".$response;
     }
     }

     curl_close($ch);
  ?>
```

Also check your API key and password one more time before sending the request whether both are correct or wrong?

Comment: Well! Thanks a lot!